# Powershell GetEnvironmentVariable vs $Env

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have run into a couple cases where I am trying to use a command via command line, but the command is not recognized. I have narrowed it down to an issue with environment variables.  In each case, the variable is present when I retrieve the variable with the underlying C# method, but not with the shorthand, $env:myVariable

For example, if I retrieve the variable like this, I will get a value.

```
 [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'Machine')
```

But, if I retrieve the variable like this, nothing is returned

```
$env:ChocolateyInstall
```

I then have to do something like this to to get my command to work.

```
$env:ChocolateyInstall = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'Machine')
```

I have not been able to find a good explanation as to why I have to do this. I've looked at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7), but nothing stands out to me. Ideally, I would like to install a CLI and then not have to deal with checking for and assigning environment variables for the command to work.

Comment: You should only ever have to do this if the env. var. has just been created in the registry, _after_ the current session was started. Otherwise, note that a `User` scope definition takes precedence over a `Machine` definition.

Comment: `$env:` like `$function:` are drives exclusive to PowerShell, you can find them with `Get-PSDrive`, you can write to these drives and create stuff for these drives, but they won't always be loaded globally, whereas `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'Machine')` will get loaded **on next startup** since environment variables are loaded on boot. To write to the drive you can use `$env:ChocolateyInstall = "Path"` and you could view it with `$env:` but not with `[Environment]` and the same goes vice versa untill you restart the machine.

Comment: @Thomas my bad, the environment drive reloads after each reboot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When opening a PowerShell session, all permanently stored environment variables<sup>1</sup> will be loaded into the Environment drive (`Env:`) of this current session ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_provider?view=powershell-7#detailed-description)):

> The Environment drive is a flat namespace containing the environment
> variables specific to the current user's session.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7#changing-environment-variables) you linked states:

> When you change environment variables in PowerShell, the change
> affects only the current session. This behavior resembles the behavior
> of the `Set` command in the Windows Command Shell and the `Setenv` command
> in UNIX-based environments. To change values in the Machine or User
> scopes, you must use the methods of the **System.Environment** class.

So defining/changing an environment variable like this:

```bsh
$env:ChocolateyInstall = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'Machine')
```

Will change it for the current session, thus being immediately effective, but will also only be valid for the current session.

The methods of `[System.Environment]` are more fine grained. There you can choose which environment variable scope to address. There are three scopes available:

- Machine
- User
- Process

The `Process` scope is equivalent to the Environment drive and covers the environment variables available in your current session. The `Machine` and the `User` scope address the permanently stored environment variables<sup>1</sup>. You can get variables from a particular scope like this:

```bsh
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'Machine')
```

And set them with:

```bsh
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall', 'any/path/to/somewhere', 'Machine')
```

If you want to have new variables from the `Machine` or `User` scope available in your current PowerShell session, you have to create a new one. But don't open a new PowerShell session from your current PowerShell session, as it will then inherit all environment variables from your current PowerShell session ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7#long-description)):

> Environment variables, unlike other types of variables in PowerShell,
> are inherited by child processes, such as local background jobs and
> the sessions in which module members run. This makes environment
> variables well suited to storing values that are needed in both parent
> and child processes.

So, to address the problem you described, you most probably changed your permanently stored environment variables<sup>1</sup>, while already having an open PowerShell session. If so, you just need to open a new (really new, see above) session and you will be able to access your environment variables via the Environment drive. Just to be clear, opening a new session will even reload environment variables of the `Machine` scope. There is no reboot required.

---

<sup>1</sup> That are the environment variables you see in the GUI when going to the *System Control Panel*, selecting *Advanced System Settings* and on the *Advanced* tab, clicking on *Environment Variable*. Those variables cover the `User` and the `Machine` scope.
Alternatively, you can open this GUI directly by executing:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thoughtful answer.  I left out one notable piece of information and that is that I'm running scripts via Octopus Deploy's script engine.  After digging into your answer, I was able to conclude that Octopus appears to not be executing the scripts in "really new" sessions, thus the environment drive is not getting 
 refreshed.