# Changing the PSModulePath in Powershell 5

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-5.0

I've used the following to permanently change the PSModulePath:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', "ABC", "Machine")
```

This works fine when I call the below (it returns "ABC"):

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', "Machine")
```

But in any Powershell Session when I run:

```
$env:PSModulePath
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;ABC
```

Where is this path coming from, is it PS5 magic? I've checked the "User" target and this is blank. It's as if something is pre-pending the PSModulePath with this default path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment drive `Env:` contains the environment variables specific to the current user's session ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_provider?view=powershell-7#detailed-description)). It is equivalent to the `Process` scope. So

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Process')
```

should be equivalent to

```
$env:PSModulePath
```

The `Process` scope contains the environment variables of a particular process. It gets constructed like this ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7#using-and-changing-environment-variables)):

> This list of variables is inherited from the parent process and is constructed from the variables in the *Machine* and *User* scopes.

As you checked both, the `Machine` and the `User` scope, and did not find the path, it has to come from the parent process, which is PowerShell itself. And this is indeed the case as can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.1#windows-powershell-startup):

> The **CurrentUser** module path is prefixed only if User scope `$env:PSModulePath` doesn't exist. Otherwise, the User scope `$env:PSModulePath` is used as defined.

As you confirmed in your question,

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'User')
```

is empty and thus `$env:PSModulePath` has been prefixed by the **CurrentUser** module path, which is `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` or `$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` depending on your [Windows version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path?view=powershell-7.1).

You can read more about environment variables in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008393/11942268).